# Convert character month name to date time object

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I must be missing something simple.

I have a data.frame of various date formats and I'm using lubridate which works great with everything except ***month names by themselves***. I can't get the month names to convert to date time objects.

```
> head(dates)
    From         To
1       June     August
2    January   December
3 05/01/2013 10/30/2013
4       July   November
5 06/17/2013 10/14/2013
6 05/04/2013 11/23/2013
```

Trying to change June into date time object:

```
> as_date(dates[1,1])
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

> as_date("June")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

- The actual year and day do not matter. I only need the month. zx8754 suggested using dummy day and year.

Comment: When year is missing, do you assume 2013, and when day is missing is it 01? Then we can paste dummy years, days, then convert.

Comment: @zx8754 The year and date don't matter, so yes, I think dummy days and years would work. Thanks

Comment: If you mean that you wish to simply convert the month value to a corresponding numeric value (i.e., "Dec" -> 12), then you could try `match(dates[1, 1], month.abb)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a custom function:

```
# dummy data
df1 <- read.table(text = "
From         To
1       June     August
2    January   December
3 05/01/2013 10/30/2013
4       July   November
5 06/17/2013 10/14/2013
6 05/04/2013 11/23/2013", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

# custom function
myFun <- function(x, dummyDay = "01", dummyYear = "2013"){
  require(lubridate)

  x <- ifelse(substr(x, 1, 3) %in% month.abb,
              paste(match(substr(x, 1, 3), month.abb),
                    dummyDay,
                    dummyYear, sep = "/"), x)
  #return date
  mdy(x)
}

res <- data.frame(lapply(df1, myFun))

res
#         From         To
# 1 2013-06-01 2013-08-01
# 2 2013-01-01 2013-12-01
# 3 2013-05-01 2013-10-30
# 4 2013-07-01 2013-11-01
# 5 2013-06-17 2013-10-14
# 6 2013-05-04 2013-11-23
```

Comment: Nice function. I think you could just do `df1[] <- lapply(df1, myFun)` in order to avoid duplicating data sets. I'm also wondering what meaning these dates have and how OP is going to differ between a real June first and some dummy one. Also, what happens if `From` will have `November` and `To` will have `August`? If you ask me, I would just close this whole thing as "unclear"

Comment: @DavidArenburg OP can use the function however they wish, I prefer to keep raw input as raw.

Comment: Have no idea what *keep raw input as raw* means, but ok I guess

Comment: @zx8754 This is a little off topic, but why do you use substr(x,1,3). I don't understand why 1 and 3 evaluates to True. Why does 1 and 2 and it evaluate it False?

Comment: @Chris because `month.abb` gives 3 letter month names, like "Jan, Feb, Mar,..., Dec". So I am saying if first 3 letters match `month.abb` names then convert to number using match.

Answer (score 8):

`lubridate` can handle converting the name or abbreviation of a month to its number when it's paired with the rest of the information needed to make a proper date, i.e. a day and year. For example:

```r
lubridate::mdy("August/01/2013", "08/01/2013", "Aug/01/2013")
#> [1] "2013-08-01" "2013-08-01" "2013-08-01"
```

You can utilize that to write a function that appends "/01/2013" to any month names (I threw in abbreviations as well to be safe). Then apply that to all your date columns (`dplyr::mutate_all` is just one way to do that).

```r
name_to_date <- function(x) {
  lubridate::mdy(ifelse(x %in% c(month.name, month.abb), paste0(x, "/01/2013"), x))
}

dplyr::mutate_all(dates, name_to_date)
#>         From         To
#> 1 2013-06-01 2013-08-01
#> 2 2013-01-01 2013-12-01
#> 3 2013-05-01 2013-10-30
#> 4 2013-07-01 2013-11-01
#> 5 2013-06-17 2013-10-14
#> 6 2013-05-04 2013-11-23
```

Answer (score 4):

The following is a crude example of how you could achieve that.

Given that dummy values are fine:

```
match(dates[1, 1], month.abb)
```

The above would return you, given that we had `Dec` in `dates[1. 1]`:

```
12
```

To generate the returned value above along with dummy number in a date format, I tried:

```
tmp = paste(match(dates[1, 1], month.abb), "2013", sep="/")
```

which gives us:

```
12/2013
```

and then lastly:

```
result = paste("01", tmp, sep="/")
```

which returns:

```
01/12/2013
```

I am sure there are more flexible approaches than this; but this is just an idea, which I just tried.

Comment: Hehe, you have just broke down my function into pieces and gave a great explanation.